# Insert password key on steganography matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, password-encryption, steganography

I need your help how to insert password key on embedding & extracting process (steganography) in matlab?

Can it make in difference function and call it on other .m file?

If there is any sugggestion/recommendation sites, please let me know.

Here is my code function for embedd/extract process on steganography.

```
function[capa,opfile,full,file]= proses_embedd(P1,Q)
P=imread(P1);
[Pm,Pn]=size(P);
I=P;
fid=fopen(Q,'rt');
[X1,co]=fread(fid,'*char');
r=1;

for q=1:co
   L(q)=uint8(X1(q));
end;

for q=1:co
    W(r:r+7)=dec2bin(L(q),8);
    r=r+8;
end;

file=r-1;
x=0;

for i=1:Pm
    if x>=(r-1)
        break;
    end;

    for j=1:2:Pn-1
        if x>=(r-1)
            break;
        end;

        p11=double(I(i,j));
        p21=double(I(i,j+1));
        d0=(p11-p21);

        if abs(d0)<8
            w0=8;
            l0=0;
        elseif abs(d0)<16&&abs(d0)>7
            w0=8;
            l0=8;
        elseif abs(d0)>15&&abs(d0)<32
            w0=16;
            l0=16;
        elseif abs(d0)>31&&abs(d0)<64
            w0=32;
            l0=32;
        elseif abs(d0)>63&&abs(d0)<128
            w0=64;
            l0=64;
        elseif abs(d0)>127&&abs(d0)<256
            w0=128;
            l0=128;
        else
            w0=0;
        end;

        if(w0>0)
            t0=floor(log2(w0));
        else
            t0=0;
        end;

        if(t0>0)
            if(x<(r-1) && x+t0>(r-1))
                b0=bin2dec(W(x+1:(r-1)));
                d00=l0+b0;
                m0=abs(d00-abs(d0));

                if((p11>=p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                    p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                    p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                end;

                if((p11<p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                    p00=p11-floor(m0/2);
                    p01=p21+ceil(m0/2);
                end;  

                if((p11>=p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                    p00=p11-ceil(m0/2);
                    p01=p21+floor(m0/2);
                end;

                if((p11<p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                    p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                    p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                end;  

                block=1;
                x=r-1; 
            end;

            if(x+t0)<=(r-1)
                 b0=bin2dec(W(x+1:x+t0));
                 d00=l0+b0;
                 m0=abs(d00-abs(d0));

                 if((p11>=p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                     p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                 end;

                 if((p11<p21)&&(d00>abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11-floor(m0/2);
                     p01=p21+ceil(m0/2);
                 end;  

                 if((p11>=p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11-ceil(m0/2);
                     p01=p21+floor(m0/2);                  
                 end;

                 if((p11<p21)&&(d00<=abs(d0)))
                     p00=p11+ceil(m0/2);
                     p01=p21-floor(m0/2);
                 end; 
                 block=1;
                 x=x+t0;           
            end;
        end;

        if block==1
            p0=p00;
            p1=p01;
            I(i,j)=p0;
            I(i,j+1)=p1;
        end;
    end;
end;

if((i==Pm)&&(j>=Pn-20))
    full=0;
else
    full=1;
end;

capa=x;
capacity=dec2bin(capa,20);
s=1;
i=Pm;
j=Pn-20;

while(s<21)
    temp1=dec2bin(I(i,j),8);
    temp1(8)=capacity(s);
    I(i,j)=bin2dec(temp1);
    s=s+1;
    j=j+1;
end;

answer = inputdlg('output image name');
answer1=strcat(answer,'.bmp');
imwrite(I,char(answer1),'bmp');
opfile=char(answer1);
```

and here is the extract process codes :

```
function [namapesan,lokasi,fid]=proses_ekstrak(P1)
I=imread(P1);
[Pm,Pn]=size(I);
s=1;
i=Pm;
j=Pn-20;

while(s<21)
    temp1=dec2bin(I(i,j),8);
    bits(s)=temp1(8);
    s=s+1;
    j=j+1;
end;

quan=bin2dec(bits);
r=quan;
ans=quan/8;
x=0;

for i=1:Pm
    if x>=(r)
        break;
    end;

    for j=1:2:Pn-1
        if x>=(r)
            break;
        end;
        p11=double(I(i,j));
        p21=double(I(i,j+1));
        d0=(p11-p21);

        if abs(d0)<8
            w0=8;
            l0=0;
        elseif abs(d0)<16&&abs(d0)>7
            w0=8;
            l0=8;
        elseif abs(d0)>15&&abs(d0)<32
            w0=16;
            l0=16;
        elseif abs(d0)>31&&abs(d0)<64
            w0=32;
            l0=32;
        elseif abs(d0)>63&&abs(d0)<128
            w0=64;
            l0=64;
        elseif abs(d0)>127&&abs(d0)<256
            w0=128;
            l0=128;
        else
            w0=0;
        end;

        if(w0>0)
            t0=floor(log2(w0));
        else
            t0=0;
        end;

        if(x<r && x+t0>r)
            dec1=abs(d0)-l0;
            t0=r-x;
            w= dec2bin(dec1,t0);
            binary(x+1:x+t0)=w(1:t0);
            x=x+t0;
        end;

        if(x+t0<=r)
            dec1=abs(d0)-l0;
            binary(x+1:x+t0)=dec2bin(dec1,t0);
            x=x+t0;
        end;
    end;
end;

x=0;
o=1;
while(o<=(quan/8))
    W(o)= bin2dec(binary(x+1:x+8));
    x=x+8;
    o=o+1;
end;

if(quan<=5000)
    disp(char(W));
end;

[namapesan, lokasi]=uiputfile('*.txt','Save Message');
fid = fopen(char(namapesan),'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s',char(W));
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking for. Don't just dump code and expect people to know what it *should* do. Also a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would help.

Comment: Hi @bdecaf I just to know how to insert password as a key on steganography process in matlab, please need your advice. Many thanks

Comment: There are many ways to go about it. You can use the password to encrypt your binary text in another string, or you can use it as a seed to permute the image indices and not embed your secret serially. You'll get more help if you have something specific in mind and have trouble implementing it.

Comment: Hi @Reti43 here is my program step. For Embedd process, 1st is choose image for cover, 2nd is choose message to hide (.txt file), 3rd is user input password as stego key that it will called again in Extract Process.

I've problem to implemented password as stego key, how to compare it when it embedd then it extracted, so if the password wrong in extract process the message won't show correctly. Please your advice, thanks

Comment: You don't need to embed the password in the secret. The idea is that the password will make the extraction impossible unless it is known. Considering you've found this code on the web, do you understand how it works so you can think of a password implementation?

Comment: yes I got this code on the web, but I modify so it can suit with my program design. Until now I don't understand about implementation password on these codes @Reti43 . Need your advice again, many thanks